# QGIS - export xyz

Tags: qgis

I would like to export a `.tiff` file of a terrain area from QGIS to easily insert it into Archicad?

Comment: English only ... bitte

Comment: how can i export an .xyz file from QGIS to get it into Archicad? I would like to export a .tiff file of a terrain area from QGIS to easily insert it into Archicad?

Comment: Well, what did you try? Have you e.g. googled for "QGIS documentation export xyz"?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Yes, I've been google for a while. I'm supposed to export a .CSV file and then convert that file to an .xyz file. But the program won't even let me save a .CSV file. Do you have any idea how I could export a terrain in Archicad simply by using a point cloud from QGIS?

Comment: What kind of formats does archicad support?

Answer (score 2):

There are two tools available in the processing toolbox that provide this functionality. Search for r.out.xyz and gdal2xyz. Be aware that the files will be much larger than the original raster file.